# ASP.NET Core routing trouble after migrating to host gator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am very new to ASP.NET and am having trouble with my project. I am building a very simple API for some data in a SQL Server database. I had this project working in Azure until I ran out of my credits there and realized how expensive it would be to host my project there. So I booted up an account at host gator, set up a new database and am trying to get it working there.

I have the app "working" in that if I got to `www.myurl.com/home` I do get the same landing page I had previously. Now, however, when I got to either the `www.myurl.com/api/models` or `www.myurl.com/api/models/id` I get an ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR saying this site can't be reached.

I really don't have much in the project but I think the relevant parts are below. Any help greatly appreciated. Let me know if there's any other information I can provide that is helpful!

`ModelsController`:

```
namespace DotNetCoreSqlDb.Controllers.Api 
{
    [Route("/api/models")]
    public class ModelsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyDatabaseContext _context;
        private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
        private readonly string _ModelItemsCacheKey = "ModelItemsList";

        public ModelsController(MyDatabaseContext context, IDistributedCache cache)
        {
            _context = context;
            _cache = cache;
        }

        // GET: Models
        [HttpGet("/api/models")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var models= _context.Model;
            
            if (models == null)
            { 
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Json(models);
        }

        // GET: Model{id}
        [HttpGet("/api/models/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int? id)
        {
            var models = _context.Model;
            var model = models.Where(model=> model.model_id == id);

            if (model == null)
            { 
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Json(model);
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Models}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

@Dai. My connections string is in `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LocalSqlServer": "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
  }
}
```

Plesk ASP.NET settings page
[image]

Comment: Where are you configuring `MyDatabaseContext`? e.g. your connection-strings? As for the HTTP/2 errors, you'll have to ask HostGator's own support about that.

Comment: `var model = models.Where(model=> model.model_id == id);` <-- Don't do this: you're returning a lazily-evaluated Linq `IQueryable<T>` which won't be evaluated until after your `Controller` becomes unreachable - instead you need to _materialize_ your data using `ToListAsync()` first, then pass the `List<T>` to `Json(model)`.

Comment: @Dai updated with my connection strings.

Comment: Where/how are you configuring EF to use the connection-string named `"LocalSqlServer"`?

Comment: From the Plesk ASP.NET Settings page

Comment: I suggest you could ask HostGator's support to understand how they host your asp.net core application and use http2 with your client browser.